# How to increase moz:shutdownTimeout parameter in Selenium Grid

Tags: spring, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver, flakyness

I am having the following error on flaky tests when executing Tests on Selenium Grid (Selenium 4 / Firefox remoteWebdriver).

````
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/session/0f47d0ef-cca4-471f-9c08-94efe5ac82f2/element/b02fc4f1-0503-46aa-a50d-6f7cd6e68c08/elements">POST&nbsp;/session/0f47d0ef-cca4-471f-9c08-94efe5ac82f2/element/b02fc4f1-0503-46aa-a50d-6f7cd6e68c08/elements</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
Command duration or timeout: 60.05 seconds```

I tried to increase timeouts (--session-timeout, --session-request-timeout) for Selenium grid nodes and hub, still having the same errors. Have found not way to increase this parameter that seems to cause errors **moz:shutdownTimeout**
````

Comment: Please add any error messages as text instead of as an image.